# Google Maps distance calculator WITH geolocation

Tags: javascript, geolocation, maps

I have a small web app that can calculate the distance between two points on Google maps.

I would like it to place the user at it's current position when loading the app. I have tried with different geolocation methods without any luck.

The best thing would be to have it calculate the distance from the users position. However, just having the users position in the web-app will be enough for me.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var directionDisplay;
    var map;


function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var copenhagen = new google.maps.LatLng(55.6771, 12.5704);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: copenhagen
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }


    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");

    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
        }
    });
    }
    </script>

    <title>Distance Calculator</title>

    <style type="text/css">

            body {
                font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
            }
            #map_canvas {
                height: 50%;
            }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <body onload="initialize()">
    <p>Enter your current location and desired destination to get the distance</p>
        <div>
            <p>
                <label for="start">Start: </label>
                <input type="text" name="start" id="start" />

                <label for="end">End: </label>
                <input type="text" name="end" id="end" />

                <input type="submit" value="Calculate Route" onclick="calcRoute()" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="distance">Distance (km): </label>
                <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" readonly="true" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to try this [link](http://studiowhiz.com/2010/10/02/google-maps-v3-distancefrom/)

```
google.maps.LatLng.prototype.distanceFrom = function(newLatLng) {
// setup our variables
var lat1 = this.lat();
var radianLat1 = lat1 * ( Math.PI  / 180 );
var lng1 = this.lng();
var radianLng1 = lng1 * ( Math.PI  / 180 );
var lat2 = newLatLng.lat();
var radianLat2 = lat2 * ( Math.PI  / 180 );
var lng2 = newLatLng.lng();
var radianLng2 = lng2 * ( Math.PI  / 180 );
// sort out the radius, MILES or KM?
var earth_radius = 3959; // (km = 6378.1) OR (miles = 3959) - radius of the earth

// sort our the differences
var diffLat =  ( radianLat1 - radianLat2 );
var diffLng =  ( radianLng1 - radianLng2 );
// put on a wave (hey the earth is round after all)
var sinLat = Math.sin( diffLat / 2  );
var sinLng = Math.sin( diffLng / 2  ); 


var a = Math.pow(sinLat, 2.0) + Math.cos(radianLat1) * Math.cos(radianLat2) * Math.pow(sinLng, 2.0);

// work out the distance
var distance = earth_radius * 2 * Math.asin(Math.min(1, Math.sqrt(a)));

// return the distance
return distance;
}
```

[distance-finder-google-maps-api](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/distance-finder-google-maps-api/)

Comment: I have tried the last link you posted (the first one wasn't really about geolocation)

Comment: But the code i posted in my question works. I just need to add the geolocation.

Comment: Yes... Can't get it working with my existing code :S

It would be great if someone could try working this out with my own code (posted in the question)

Answer (score 1):

To get the user's position using javascript :

```
var showPosition = function (position) {
    var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    // Do whatever you want with userLatLng.
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition); // Attach showPosition Callback which will be executed as soon as position is available. Remember it needs user confirmation.
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Stouffi/FCFSW/, for example.

**UPDATE:**

Youd need to change the onclick callback of your calcRoute button. The new one will request user's position. Once position is acquired, calcRoute is called.

```
function findCurrentLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(calcRoute);
}
```

In calcRoute, position object will be available as argument, you need to convert him into a LatLng object to deal with google directions service.

```
function calcRoute(currentLocation) {
    // create a LatLng object from the position object.
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLocation.coords.latitude, currentLocation.coords.longitude);
    // Continue with your original code.
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    // etc.
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Stouffi/mCYTf/

Comment: Great! Its asking me to access my location now. 

I just need to know where to put this in my code, to make it show up on the map. 

Sorry for the JS rookie questions..

Comment: @user1749428 - What are the expected values in your input fields ? string, latitude and longitude or both ?

Comment: Both i guess. Users can input names of cities, addresses, etc. Not coordinates.

Comment: @user1749428 - Did you read the **updated** answer? Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes i think so! I am having some problems putting the code together though...

Can you help me by taking my original code from my question edit it with your suggestions? Thanks :)

Comment: @user1749428 - As indicated in my updated answer, please see [http://jsfiddle.net/Stouffi/mCYTf/](http://jsfiddle.net/Stouffi/mCYTf/). It shows your code with a few changes to get directions from user's location to a desired destination.